# Run orientdb server from c#

Tags: c#, database, process, orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I try run OrientDB server from c# code. When I run via Powershell my database works, but when I try run from code I get error like don't have connect to db.
I thought problem is how long process starts but I used Thread.Sleep(20000) after processOrient.Start and it didn't help too.
Other servers starts very well from code (but .exe files)
My code:

```
 ProcessStartInfo processInfoOrient = new ProcessStartInfo()
 {
       FileName = @"B:\db\orientdb-3.0.29\bin\server.bat",           
       RedirectStandardError = true,
       RedirectStandardOutput = true,
       UseShellExecute = false,
       CreateNoWindow = false,
       WorkingDirectory = @"B:\db\orientdb-3.0.29\bin"
 };

 Process processOrient = new Process();
 processOrient.StartInfo = processInfoOrient;
 processOrient.Start();
```

How Can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: like always the details are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run bat-file you need to have UseShellExecute = true.

Comment: Thank you! I had to delete  "RedirectStandardError = true,
       RedirectStandardOutput = true" and with UseShellExecute = true is working well.